# Horizontal scrolling

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, scrollbars

I would like to be able to scroll horizontally with my mouse wheel and holding something like Alt. I have had to resort to making the scrollbars fat and fugly in the meantime. Running elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya on a desktop, so not trackpad scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it used to be possible to scroll horizontally while holding down the Shift key while scrolling, that unfortunately doesn't work anymore.

There is a workaround that might do the trick for you using xbindkeys and a small script, though (as originally described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112351)).This would allow you to toggle back and forth between vertical and horizontal scrolling by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + Right mouse buton.

Open a terminal and do the following:

1.Install xbindkeys:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

2.Create the toggle script and open it

```
>> ~/.toggle_script.sh  
scratch-text-editor ~/.toggle_script.sh
```

3.Paste this into the file and save

```
#!/bin/sh
on()
{
  xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9 10'
}

off()
{
  xmodmap -e 'pointer = default'
}

if xmodmap -pp | grep -q '4.*6'; then
  off
else
  on
fi
```

4.Make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/.toggle_script.sh
```

5.Create the config file for xbindkeys and execute xbindkeys

```
echo $'\"~/.toggle_script.sh\"\n\tcontrol+b:3' >.xbindkeysrc
xbindkeys
```

You should now be able to toggle back and forth between scrolling modes by pressing
<kbd>Control</kbd> + Right mouse click

Please tell me if this works for you :)

Comment: There seems to be [another problem.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13505533/) I tried to install a character map indicator earlier today to no avail. Could this be interfering?

Comment: I don't think this is related. scratch-text-editor gives me the same error messages, it doesn't seem to influence functionality for me. You could always use a different text editor, though, I personally prefer gedit. Other than that, please let me know if the solution above did the trick for you.